# What does the "submitting" I9 form?

Tags: united-states, employment

I'm a graduate student at a US university and I work as a Graduate assistant in the department. It's been around one year I have been working. I'm also an International student who can only work on-campus.

Recently I have decided that I want to **transfer** to a another University and the classes will begin at that university from august. I have summer work at current university which could take till august.

The HR department of the university I'm going to transfer, sent me an offer letter and  a **I9** form.

Should I fill the form and submit to the university where I will be start working from August even though currently i'm working at my current university?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to accept the offer, return the I9 to the department that sent it to you. It will have no effect on your relationship with your current school/employer (ie: sending it to your new job now does not prevent you from continuing at your current job), but is required for the work you will begin in August.